# Adding a script with a React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add inline scripting to a React component:
I have my custom hook:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useScript = url => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, [url]);
};

export default useScript;
```

Which I use like so:

```
import useScript from 'hooks/useScript';

const MyComponent = () => {
  useScript('path/to/my.js');
}
```

Script added to the document after SPA navigation event but it doesn't add events to my buttons without reloading the page.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. If you are going to give 2 images explain the difference and what you would expect, don't let people play the diff game and have to make assumptions or you'll likely get poor quality answers.
First, you should detail the issue, is your script not added to the document or not properly executed ?

Comment: Also could you be more precise about what you mean by "without reloading" ? is it when mounting the component after load, something like an SPA navigation event ?

Comment: Thank you @Apolo. I changed my question. I want to add script to the component after SPA navigation event.

Comment: I think the issue is probably inside the script you load, can you share it ? Would need to check how the function adding event listeners is called

Comment: I load those scripts: https://www.w3.org/TR/2019/NOTE-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20190207/examples/carousel/carousel-1/js/carousel.js, https://www.w3.org/TR/2019/NOTE-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20190207/examples/carousel/carousel-1/js/carouselItem.js, https://www.w3.org/TR/2019/NOTE-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20190207/examples/carousel/carousel-1/js/carouselButtons.js, https://www.w3.org/TR/2019/NOTE-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20190207/examples/carousel/carousel-1/js/pauseButton.js

Comment: the issue is that these scripts execute when the window "load" event is fired, which only happen when loading a page. You need to initialize your elements manually

Comment: @Apolo Thank you. I have one more question. If I change those files how I can add my own js to react project? Do I need to add js files to node_modules folder? Sorry, I'm new in react and in programming at all.

Comment: You shouldn't put files inside node_modules yourself, that's where your dependancy manager (npm or yarn usually) install things. The answer to that question would be too long for an answer yet a comment, I strongly advise you to find a tutorial about how to setup a React project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem inside one of the added scripts. I changed the way of adding script. I exported the function inside js, then I imported this function inside my component and then I used useEffect.

```
import { MyFunction } from './myscript.js';

const MyComponent = () => {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        MyFunction();              
     }, []);
    
    return(
       ......
    )
```